# High wall time with synchronous Calls to Datastore in Apache Beam transform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have been investigating a Beam job (that uses GCP Dataflow) that has been running very slow. Using the GCP profiler, I was able to identify that most of the wall time was spent waiting on calls to Datastore (within a beam transform) using the Standard Java Datastore library (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries). I wrote a test job that just makes simple datastore reads within a beam transform and saw the same results. Here is a screenshot of the profiler

[image]

You can see in the screenshot that on average it is taking around 19s to run these simple Datastore queries. I understand it is best practice to use the beam datastore library in order to parallelize/batch these calls to Datastore but for our use case we need these sequential synchronous reads within the beam transform. Anyways I was wondering if anyone had any insight into why these calls might be taking as long as they do? You can see in the screenshot that most of the wall time is spent waiting on the SocketInputStream.socketRead0() method which indicates possible network or remote server latency.

Here is a screenshot of the test job DoFn code i wrote that i ran the above profile on:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is the right information here to help.  Things to consider: 1) Where are you running dataflow vs where is your database?  (2) How much data is being transferred as part of your query? (3) Are you on Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode?

Comment: Another possibility, are you deleting data with the value you are querying on?  Details on deletions and compactions are at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#deletions .

Comment: Hi Jim, I ended up putting log statements (with timestamps) before and after the query. As it turns out the query was, for the most part, taking around 50ms with some outliers around 200ms. This completely contradicts what we saw in the profiler. Or maybe our interpretation of the profile. So it is either the profiler is wrong or our interpretation of the profile is wrong. Still looking into this. Thanks for your response though!